# looking for reference of example shown in "Basic notions of algebra" Shafarevich

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I'm looking for reference of example shown in Shafarevich's book "Basic notion of algebra".
An example I'm looking for is from chapter4:"Homomorphisms and Ideals", example number 13.
which states correspondence between polynomial ring generated by commutative differential operators and points on algebraic curves.
I want to learn more about this topic, but unfortunately I couldn't find any reference for this. 
It would be helpful if someone knows any literature or reference on this topic.
thanks.

Comment: Shafarevich and operator algebras.  That's a first

Comment: Shafarevich and algebraic geometry. That's second.

Answer (score 0):

i found literature on this example.
this was from "Burchnall-Chaundy theory", if anyone else is also interested in this example.

thanks for comments.